# No Module Named 'apscheduler' Error When Running the .exe file. --hidden-file command Doesn't Work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, apscheduler

I've recently created an .exe file of my program with pyinstaller using this code:

```
pyinstaller --onefile 'myprogram.py'
```

This worked for some other programs but when I ran this .exe file

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "myprogram.py", line 3, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'
> [18908] Failed to execute script myprogram

When searching through internet, I found hidden import command and tried it using this code but it gave the same error message:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=apscheduler 'myprogram.py'
```

I don't know if it's related to the problem but I think it's worth noting that the import command of APscheduler looks like this:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
```

Is there anyway I can fix this issue quickly?
Pyinstaller version:4.3
Apscheduler version: 3.7.0